# How to manually trigger a change detection in a ComponentRef

Tags: javascript, angular

i try to create a dynamic component and trigger a change detection by the ComponentRef

I try to create a dynamic component and trigger a change detection by the ComponentRef, but it doesnt work.
Component failed to trigger onChanges event.

```
 const dynamicCompContent = document.createElement(`${mountElId}-dynamic-component`);

    // Create the component and wire it up with the element
    const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    const ModalContentComponentRef: ComponentRef<any> = factory.create(this.injector, [], dynamicCompContent);
    // Attach to the view so that the change detector knows to run
    this.applicationRef.attachView(ModalContentComponentRef.hostView);

    // Listen to the close event
    this.compIdToSubscriptionMap[compInsId] = this.destroyModalSubscription.subscribe((compId: string) => {
      if (compId !== ModalContentComponentRef.instance.compId) { return; }

      this.applicationRef.detachView(ModalContentComponentRef.hostView);
      try { dynamicCompContent.parentNode.removeChild(dynamicCompContent); } catch (err) { }
      this.compIdToSubscriptionMap[compId].unsubscribe();
      delete this.compIdToSubscriptionMap[compId];
    });

    // Set the params
    const compData = { input1:1, input2: 2 };
    const updateObject = { ...compData, compId: compInsId, mountElId };
    for (const key of Object.keys(updateObject)) {
      ModalContentComponentRef.instance[key] = updateObject[key];
    }
    // const cdr = this.injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef); // it can not trigger a onChange event
    // ModalContentComponentRef.instance.cdr = cdr; // it can not trigger a onChange event
    // ModalContentComponentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges(); // it can not trigger a onChange event
    // ModalContentComponentRef.instance?.cdr?.detectChanges(); // it can not trigger a onChange event
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```js
componentRef.instance.dynamicData = 'Hello, dynamically created component!';

// Manually trigger change detection for the dynamically created component.
componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
```

I was watching the doc of ComponentRef and saw that each instance of ComponentRef as already injected changeDetectorRef (more info [here](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ComponentRef-class.html) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/core/src/render3/component_ref.ts)).

Hope to help you!